# $2^{m+1}-2^n\geq(m-n)^2$

Tags: inequality

So basically, I'm trying to see if this equality holds for large enough $n$ and such that $m\geq n$. However, Wolfram Alpha won't show me much, so I'm here to see if anyone has a solution for this.

Also, I have no idea how to approach this problem, which is why I didn't provide any work of my own.

Comment: A very broad hint: since you know that $m\geq n$, consider setting $m=k+n$ and rephrasing the problem in terms of $k=m-n$ and $n$. You should be able to factor the LHS into two pieces each of which you have a good size for...

Comment: Hint: $2^{m+1}-2^n\geq 2^m\geq m^2\geq (m-n)^2$. These inequalities aren't always true, but try to figure out when they are.

Comment: Alright, just a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^{m+1}-2^n = 2^{m-n}(2^{n+1}-2^{2n-m})>2^{m-n} \geq (m-n)^2$. This is true since $n+1 \geq 2n-m \iff m\geq n-1$ which is true since you are given that $m \geq n$. The second inequality is proven via induction on $m-n$, and is easy to do.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me then why [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Summation+from+k%3Dn+to+k%3Dm+2%5Ek+%3E+%28m-n%29%5E2) gives this weird inequality graph.

Comment: Because it shows also cases where $m$ and $n$ are negative. If you look at the first quadrant, all of $n\leq m$ is blue.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice. Thanks a lot for taking away my confusion. :)

Comment: @Hasan Saad You too , buddy .

Answer (score 1):

Fix $n$, and write $m=n+k$. Then the right-hand-side is $k^2$, and the left-hand-side is
$$
2^{m+1}-2^n=2^n2^{k+1}-2^n=2^n(2^{k+1}-1).
$$
The inequality $2^{k+1}-1\geq k^2$ holds for all $k\geq0$, so 
$$
2^{m+1}-2^n=2^n(2^{k+1}-1)\geq2^nk^2\geq k^2=(m-n)^2.
$$
So the inequality holds for all $n\geq0$ and all $m\geq n$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me then why [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Summation+from+k%3Dn+to+k%3Dm+2%5Ek+%3E+%28m-n%29%5E2) gives this weird inequality graph.

Comment: @HasanSaad WA shows the set of all real number pairs $(m,n)$ such that $2^{m+1}-2^n>(m-n)^2$.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice. Thanks a lot for taking away my confusion. :)